# Convolution of impulse responses of different sampling rates

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, convolution, sampling

I am building a cascade of filters (a CIC decimator followed by a low pass filter) and I am interested in the Frequency and Impulse response.

Knowing that the CIC decimator has a similar impulse response as a moving average filter (MA), I am calculating the impulse response of the CIC decimator in the following way

```
%parameters of cic
D=300; %deci factor
M=1;   %delays of comb
Stages=3; 
% get impulse response estimated based on MA
N=M*D;
B=ones(1,N);
B2=conv(B,B);
B3=conv(B2,B);
b_cic=B3*N^(-Stages); % FIR coefs and impulse response
```

Let the sampling rate of my input signal be 600kHz, this would mean that the output of the CIC decimator is at 2kHz. Lets assume that the coefficient of the FIR low pass filter are as follows

```
b_lp=[b_1 b_2 b_3 b_4 b_5]; % the values are not important right now
```

So here comes my question, I could estimate the filter response of the cascade by multiplying the frequency responses (I know I have to take into account the different sampling rates and length of the responses):

```
[Hcic,Fcic]=freqz(b_cic,1,300*1000,fs);
[Hlp,Flp]=freqz(b_lp,1,1000,fs/300);
```

However, I would like to know whether it is possible to convolute the impulse responses in the time domain taking the downsampling into account?
For example something like:

```
b_cas = con(b_cic,b_lp); % <--- I know that this does not work due to different sampling rates
```

So far I was not able to find something using google or here.

I am aware that I could use build-in matlab function for the different filters and cascade them using

```
dsp.FilterCascade
```

Comment: I am pretty sure I am missing the point but why such an involved process? Can you not simply send an impulse into your decimator and low pass filter? Since all your filters seem to be non-recursive your impulse response should be off finite duration. Calculate the FFT of your impulse response you capture and you have the spectrum.

Comment: The problem is, that the impulse response of the CIC is estimated with the MA impulse response. However this estimation is not taking the down-sampling into account. So using the LP filter which is setup for a different sampling rate would result in a wrong Impulse and the estimation of the frequency response out of that would be incorrect too. As mentioned, I am aware of possibilities to overcome this problem, multiplication in frequency domain or building filter objects and cascading them. However I would like to know if I can do this in time domain based on the here described approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the the frequency response of both filters at the input rate (600 kHz).  If you upsample the impulse response of the FIR low pass filter up to the input rate of CIC demicator and convolve the two you should get the combined impulse response of the cascade of the two filters together.

Comment: I tried zero-padding the b_lp first but I haven't thought about upsampling. It worked, thanks

Comment: Zero-padding and upsampling should be the same.  Did you use matlab's upsample function?

Comment: Yes, I upsampled the impulse response of the low pass filter with matlab's upsample function. This put the zeros in between coefficients and the result was perfect. Just adding zero to the end of the impulse response did not help me. Nevertheless, thanks for your help.